# Show/Hide infopath groups programmatically depending on checkbox selection

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010

i'm new to infopath and need to ammend an existing infopath 2010 form. The users only want certain section groups to appear based on the users choice via checkboxes. Currently there are conditional rules in place for each group on the form which are working to hide/show the sections depending on whcih checkbox or checkboxes are selected.(each checkbox relates to a group). There are 19 checkboxes and related groups, the users can select 1 or more groups.

The problem is when users tick the checkbox , there is a delayed reaction seeing as there are so many condtional checks taking place on each click.The users dont like this. they would rather selct all the checkboxes they want , and then click a button to do all the work at once(instead of on each checkbox). So i've been trying to programmatically access the groups from the code behind the buttons to hide/show them depending on which checkboxes are selected. Is it even possible to set the hide/show property of a group in the code behind ?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show or hide sections directly with code, but you can affect data sources, which in turn can trigger rules.

See here for updating the data source programatically:
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/programmatically-enable-disable-control-infopath-form.htm